# Azure Service Fabric- Trigger Service/Actor when message arrives in Azure Storage Queue

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-storage-queues

I have a azure storage queue (Request Queue)that contains list of tasks to perform. 
My Service fabric app consists of a public web api that enqueues tasks in this queue. There will be a stateless service which will process these tasks one by one and put the results in another azure storage Response queue(NOT IReliableQueue).

A windows service sitting in the app server listens to this response queue and does some processing and puts the final response in third azure storage queue which is then drained by separate azure stateless service.

I'm struggling to find a way to trigger azure services when message arrives in the azure storage queue. I know traditionally, azure queues can trigger webjobs but how can same be achieved in SF world?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to run an Azure WebJob inside of a Service Fabric service. See an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332081/webjob-sdk-not-working-when-running-in-a-service-fabric-application).