# Fatal Error - Azure Storage Queues with Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-webjobssdk, azure-storage-queues

I have been trying to add listeners for messages posted on the Azure storage Queues inside of the Service Fabric. The code snippets that I have used in my stateless service are as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Fabric;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Runtime;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue;
using Notification;

namespace My.Notification
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An instance of this class is created for each service instance by the Service Fabric runtime.
    /// </summary>'
    internal sealed class Notification : StatelessService
    {
        public Notification(StatelessServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
        {




        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Optional override to create listeners (e.g., TCP, HTTP) for this service replica to handle client or user requests.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A collection of listeners.</returns>
        protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
        {
            return new ServiceInstanceListener[0];
        }

        //First option
        protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();
            config.DashboardConnectionString = "string";
            config.StorageConnectionString = "stringg";
            config.Queues.BatchSize = 10;
            config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 8;
            config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            var host = new JobHost(config);

            //Breaks below
            await host.CallAsync(typeof(Notification).GetMethod("ProcessMethod"), cancellationToken);
            host.RunAndBlock();

        }

        //Second option
        protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var config = new JobHostConfiguration
                {
                    DashboardConnectionString = "string",//Real connection string,
                    StorageConnectionString = "string",
                    Queues =
                    {
                        BatchSize = 1,
                        MaxDequeueCount = 3,
                        MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
                    }
                };
                var host = new JobHost(config);

                //Breaks here
                await host.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceStartupFailedEvent(ex.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }

        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public static async Task ProcessMethod(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            long iterations = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                //log
                Trace.TraceInformation(">>[{0}]ProcessMethod Working-{1}", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), ++iterations);
                //sleep for 5s
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancellationToken);
            }
        }


        //[Timeout("00:03:00")]
        public static void ProcessNotificationsInQueue([QueueTrigger("emailqueue")] string message)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation(">ProcessNotificationsInQueue invoked with notification:{0}", message);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is shown below. I have tried both ways and I am not sure how to get more details other than this. Some posts have recommended that we enable MDAs and I have also tried that. Others have pointed it might be a CLR issue. I have also had a look at this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332081/webjob-sdk-not-working-when-running-in-a-service-fabric-application) and I have almost the same default setup.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok figured out the solution based off the discussion [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/628)
My version of Azure WebJobs had a dependency on Storage. The version of Storage was 9.0.0 which had a method removed in it. Non-availability of that method was the thing causing this crash.